# p.Shift undefined (type types.Parser has no field or method Shift) Golang

Tags: file, go, module

I'm encountering this problem where I started to separate my Go code into modules, and I've come across this issue. I basically separated all the structs and interfaces into "main/parser/types." When I try to use something like in this case:

```golang
import "github.com/user/packageName/main/types"

func (p *types.Parser) ParseTesting() types.Expr {
    token := p.Shift()
}
```

It throws me this error: p.Shift undefined (type types.Parser has no field or method Shift). It's like it doesn't exist when actually it does.

This is the main/parser/types code:

```golang
type Parser struct {
    Tokens []lexer.Token
}
```

And the functions like `p.Shift()` are located at the same folder level as the main function of the package `Parser`. For those functions, I put them in a file called `helpers.go` where I have the following:

```golang
package parser

import (
    "github.com/user/packageName/main/lexer"
    "github.com/user/packageName/main/parser/types"
)

func NewParser(tokens []lexer.Token) types.Parser {
    return types.Parser{
        Tokens: tokens,
    }
}

func (p types.Parser) At() lexer.Token {
    if len(p.Tokens) > 0 {
        return p.Tokens[0]
    }
    return lexer.Token{}
}

func (p types.Parser) Shift() lexer.Token {
    token := p.Tokens[0]
    p.Tokens = p.Tokens[1:]
    return token
}
```

I'm new to Golang, and it's the first time I'm doing things with modules and splitting code into different files.

Comment: Methods cannot be added to existing types. You need to define the method in the same package. If you’re new to Go, start with the tour of Go which mentions this here https://go.dev/tour/methods/3